# Get entire record for Max value (date) in one column

Tags: date, ms-access, transactions, max

I am trying to query data for transactions. I want to get multiple columns for the latest dated transaction. PONumber, Vendor, Price for each item, last time purchased. For example:

Data:

```
PONumber    Item    Vendor    Price    DateOrdered
1           ABC     Wal-Mart  1.00     10/29/12
2           ABC     BestBuy   1.25     10/20/12
3           XYZ     Wal-Mart  2.00     10/30/12
4           XYZ     HomeDepot 2.50     9/14/12
```

Desired Result Set:

```
PONumber    Item    Vendor    Price    DateOrdered
1           ABC     Wal-Mart  1.00     10/29/12
3           XYZ     Wal-Mart  2.00     10/30/12
```

Trying to use max function on DateOrdered, but when I include the vendor I get the last purchase for each vendor and item (too many rows). I need one record for each item. Any ideas on how to accomplish? Using MS Access 2007 with ODBC to oracle tables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bill Karwin has an elegant RDBMS-agnostic approach to this very problem: [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/123481/154439).  You'd have to do some benchmarking with your actual data to see whether his approach would work better or worse than @Remou's.

Comment: @user714965 So it is. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
   tran.PONumber, 
   tran.Item, 
   tran.Vendor, 
   tran.Price, 
   tran.DateOrdered
FROM tran
WHERE tran.DateOrdered = (
   SELECT Max(DateOrdered) 
   FROM tran t 
   WHERE t.item=tran.item)
```

Where tran is your table.